# Reading in a pprinted file in Python

Tags: python, serialization, deserialization

I have a long-running script that collates a bunch of data for me. Without thinking too much about it, I set it up to periodically serialize all this data collected out to a file using something like this:

```
pprint.pprint(data, open('my_log_file.txt', 'w'))
```

The output of `pprint` is perfectly valid Python code. Is there an easy way to read in the file into memory so that if I kill the script I can start where I left off? Basically, is there a function which parses a text file as if it were a Python value and returns the result?

Comment: It really depends on what you are pretty-printing... You might be able to use `json.load` if you're just printing `dict`, `list` and such.

Comment: It's definitely not valid json.

Comment: Does it stay valid python if you just kill the script? You could check the [parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/parser.html) module.

Comment: The file itself isn't that big, in not worried about killing it while it's writing the file. I mean, I guess I could just add `data=` to the front of the file with a text editor and rename the file to end in `.py`, then import it as a module. That just seems clunky though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you are writing **one** object to a log file?  In that case you can simply use eval to turn it back in to a valid python object.

```
from pprint import pprint

# make some simple data structures
dct = {k: v for k, v in zip('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', range(26))}

# define a filename
filename = '/tmp/foo.txt'

# write them to some log
pprint(dct, open(filename, 'w'))

# open them back out of that log and use the readlines() function
# to let python split on the new lines for us
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    obj = eval(f.read())

print(type(obj))
print(obj)
```

It gets a little trickier if you are trying to write multiple objects to this file, but that is still doable.

The output of the above script is

```
<type 'dict'>
{'a': 0, 'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'e': 4, 'd': 3, 'g': 6, 'f': 5, 'i': 8, 'h': 7, 'k': 10, 'j': 9, 'm': 12, 'l': 11, 'o': 14, 'n': 13, 'q': 16, 'p': 15, 's': 18, 'r': 17, 'u': 20, 't': 19, 'w': 22, 'v': 21, 'y': 24, 'x': 23, 'z': 25}
```

Does this solve your problem?